# Selecting a folder using msoFileDialogFolderPicker

Tags: excel, vba

To copy a Pictures/Images a code is written, To copy images i have to set the folder path, now i am currently manually setting the folder path, As the code is to be used by many user i want to give a option for user to select the folder.

**Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)** Vba has got this method to set folder path, correct me if am wrong.

Now i have to implement the above method to select folder by user for below code.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rgTarget As Range
Dim RowI As Long, ColumnI As Long

    Folderpath = "C:\Users\sandeep.hc\Pics"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    NoOfFiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files.Count
    Set listfiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files
    For Each fls In listfiles
       strCompFilePath = Folderpath & "\" & Trim(fls.Name)
        If strCompFilePath <> "" Then
            If (InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "jpg", vbTextCompare) > 1 _
            Or InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "jpeg", vbTextCompare) > 1 _
            Or InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "png", vbTextCompare) > 1) Then
    RowI = 29
    ColumnI = ColumnI + 1
    Set rgTarget = Cells(RowI, ColumnI)
    Application.ActiveSheet.Shapes.Addpicture strCompFilePath, False, True, rgTarget.Left, rgTarget.Top, 875, 400
    ColumnI = ColumnI + 17
    End If

End If
Next

End Sub
```

In above code am setting folder path manually in code.

**Folderpath = "C:\Users\sandeep.hc\Pics"**

Instead i want it by user like below part of code,

**Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)**

help is needed to implement msoFileDialogFolderPicker to above code.

Comment: I am working on your question and suitably modifying the code.

Comment: I have modified the program. I have included a function incorporating Application.FileDialog Method which gives a option to user for selecting the folder. This program works for me. One point is worth mentioning that I normally work with Option Explicit incorporated in the VBE, which invariably requires that all variables are explicitly mentioned. Please tweak picture parameters as per your requirements.

Comment: Please take care of your health and take your own time to work it out as per your convenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please incorporate following code in your routine and it shall enable you to do what you want to do.

```
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim myExtension As String
    Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    'Optimize Macro Speed
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
    Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
    .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

    'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
    myPath = myPath
    If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

    'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
    myExtension = "*.xls" 'change extension as per your requirement

    'Target Path with Ending Extension
    myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)
    'Loop through each Excel file in folder
    Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
    Set sht = wb1.Worksheets("Your_Sheet")

    '.....do something here......

    'Save and Close Workbook
     wb1.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Get next file name
     myFile = Dir
    Loop



ResetSettings:
    'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'Message Box when tasks are completed
    MsgBox "Job done!"
```

**EDIT**
I have modified the program. I have included a function incorporating Application.FileDialog Method which gives a option to user for selecting the folder. This program works for me. One point is worth mentioning that I normally work with Option Explicit incorporated in the VBE, which invariably requires that all variables are explicitly mentioned. Please tweak picture parameters as per your requirements.

```
 Sub Picinsert()

    Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook

    Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Folderpath = GetFolder()
    'Folderpath = "C:\Excelvba_exp" 'change as per your requirement
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    NoOfFiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files.Count
    Set listfiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files
    For Each fls In listfiles
       strCompFilePath = Folderpath & "\" & Trim(fls.Name)
        If strCompFilePath <> "" Then
            If (InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "jpg", vbTextCompare) > 1 _
            Or InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "jpeg", vbTextCompare) > 1 _
            Or InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "png", vbTextCompare) > 1) Then
                 counter = counter + 1
                  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & counter).Value = fls.Name
                  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & counter).ColumnWidth = 25
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & counter).RowHeight = 100
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & counter).Activate
                Call insert(strCompFilePath, counter)
                Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
            End If
        End If
    Next
    mainWorkBook.Save
End Sub

Function insert(PicPath, counter)
'MsgBox PicPath
    With ActiveSheet.Pictures.insert(PicPath)
        With .ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Width = 50
            .Height = 70
        End With
        .Left = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & counter).Left
        .Top = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & counter).Top
        .Placement = 1
        .PrintObject = True
    End With
End Function
Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim dlg                   As FileDialog
    Set dlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If dlg.Show = -1 Then
        GetFolder = dlg.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End Function
```

[image: snapshot showing program results]

Comment: I not able to set the folder using above code and use that for importing images... as am i novice to programming the method of using the code and placement of code would be wrong. please help me in understanding it

Comment: @sandeep please mention in simple words what you want to do. As I understand you are picking pictures from a directory. Then you want to add these pictures to cells of a worksheet. Please describe fully your objective. I will then simulate that situation on my PC and send you the fully working code.

Comment: @skkakar I want to import picture from a directory to excel cells, So i have written code, in that code i am setting the directory location manually, instead i want to have a option to set the directory location rather than changing in code.

Comment: @sandeep I have tested your code on standalone basis, it is giving many errors. No. of variables are not declared. Syntax of this line seems to be faulty ~Set listfiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files~. Compiler is not accepting it. Have you checked your program working even with hard coded path.

Comment: @sandeep I have made some changes in your program routine as the program routine posted by you was not working for me. I have uploaded the [zipped file along with pictures to dropbox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65565270/stackoverflow/Jun_2016/Insert_pic.zip). Please tweak with it to make it working as per your requirement and once you are satisfied . Please upload the amended file. In case you have problem in uploading then I will share my email with you. In a simpler way directory location can also be taken from any of the worksheet cell where you can change any time.

Comment: @skkakar, thanks, i was sick yest so could not look and respond to it thanks, i will use the code now and let you know

Comment: Perfect sir It worked like a charm.. thanks a lot... lot more to learn.. thanks once again accepted as answer.

Comment: @sandeep I am glad that it worked for you. Please note that where option explicit is used all variables are to be declared explicitly that is the reason some of your code fragments gave problem to me. Later on I did not use option explicit to avoid conflicts in building up a workable code collected from very different situations.